# hotkeys does not work when send is in loop

Tags: autohotkey

Assume this code:

```
Loop
{
    if enabled
        Send, /
}

m::
    enabled := !enabled
Return
```

I want to toggle sending `/` to a Notepad for example. But if I run this code by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> on keyboard, then pressing the M key again does not disable sending.
Looks like the `send` command in the Loop cause this issue since Ive tried using `msgbox` which does not disable the m key.
How can I make this code to work? (SendInput and Play does not work too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your loop is blocking any other execution. Unless that loop is the only thing in your script, you generally want to avoid using loops and use [timers](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) instead.

[Timers](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) don't block further execution but act more like their own thread. Here's an example using a timer:

```
slashTimerActive := 0

m::
    if (!slashTimerActive)
        SetTimer, SendSlash, 100 ; Call the sub every 100ms
    else
        SetTimer, SendSlash, Off

    slashTimerActive := !slashTimerActive ; Flip the variable
return

; Subroutine
SendSlash:
    SendInput, /
return
```

Comment: Thanks . its good, but you know Im a fan of expression like coding not command line ...  does set timer support expression?

Comment: @TechLife I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "expression like coding".

Comment: I dont know if you have read the ahk help file but he has said that codes like `SubStr("I'm scripting, awesome!", 16)` is an expression or Function and `StringReplace, Output, Input, AutoHotKey, AutoHotkey, ALL` are command line coding. and the main difference is that you use `:=` istead of `=` in expressions. But anyway I can see that `SetTimer` has no function like alternative. thanks the code you given works.

Comment: @TechLife Ah, yeah some are are functions, and others are commands. There are some timer-functions, like [`SetTimerEx()`](http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1948), but unless you have a really special use-case you're usually fine with the normal SetTimer command.