# Start/stop the loop on keypress only works occasionally

Tags: autohotkey

I wonder if there's something wrong with my code. I try to write a toggle code using <kbd>F2</kbd> to spam <kbd>ctrl</kbd>. It does the spam job fairly well but when I press <kbd>F2</kbd> again to toggle it off, it only works occasionally. Wonder if the spamming interfere with my <kbd>F2</kbd> key that would throw it off. Below is the code. Also, could I get a modifier so that the code would run on a separate window on the background?

```
F2::
Toggle := !Toggle
loop
{ If not Toggle
    { 
    Send, {LCtrl Up}   
      break
    }
   Send, {LCtrl Down}
   sleep, 200
   Send, {LCtrl Up}  
}
Return
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30101897/4157407

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
; autoexecute-section (top of the script):
loop_enabled := false ; the loop is disabled by default

#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2 ; allows us to invoke F2 even if the previous invocation of F2 hasn't completed.

; Press F2 down to enable the loop (the $ symbol facilitates the "P" mode of GetKeyState below).
$F2:: loop_enabled := true

#If (loop_enabled) ; If you enable the loop by pressing F2 down

    $F2 Up::  ; release F2 to start the loop
        ToolTip, Looping
        Loop
        {
            Send, {LCtrl Down}
            Loop 20
            {
                If !GetKeyState("F2", "P") 
                    sleep, 10
            }
            Send, {LCtrl Up}
            If GetKeyState("F2", "P") ; by pressing F2 while the loop is enabled
            {
              Send, {Blind}{LCtrl Up}
              ToolTip
              loop_enabled := false      ; disable and
                    break                ; terminate the loop
            }
        }
    Return

#If
```

Comment: I just test it and it seems to be better. I need to read up on how it works, but big thanks

Comment: Changed "Sleep 200" to "Sleep 20x10 ms" to make break faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is Ok. This happens because the loop takes the control of the process and at those moments the hotkey is not responsive - so it is by design so.
For this application I would write the whole app as a loop. This is a bit less compact but it should be robust and makes clear what exactly happens.

Below is a working example.
To adjust the speed of repetition - change `T_press` and `T_release` constants.
Also you can change the `sleep 10` to increase/decrease the speed of the loop.

```
Toggle := 0
ticks := 0          ; 'clock' counter

R_prev := getkeystate("F2")

T_press := 4            ; ticks before  Ctrl press
T_release := 40     ; ticks before Ctrl release  

tooltip,  Paused

loop
{ 
    sleep 10            ; loop interval
    R := getkeystate("F2") 
    RX := (R > R_prev)
    R_prev := R
    if RX {
        if Toggle {
            Toggle := 0
            ticks := 0
            send {LCtrl up}  
            tooltip,  Paused
        } else {
            Toggle := 1
        }
    }

    if Toggle {
        ticks += 1
        if (ticks = T_press) {
            send {LCtrl down}
            ; tooltip,  Pressed -- %ticks%
        }
        if (ticks = T_release) {
            send {LCtrl up}  
            ; tooltip,  Released -- %ticks%     
            ticks := 0
        }
        tooltip,  ctrl_on: %pressed% --- %ticks%
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good approach is to use [Timers](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm).

Timers turn out to be interruptable so there should be no issues with stopping them immediately.
For your task - the trick is to set two timers with the same period and always start them with an offset.
(see the `sleep 120` line). This and the period can be adjusted to your needs.

```
settimer, fire_stop, 400
settimer, fire, 400
settimer, fire, off
settimer, fire_stop, off

Toggle := 0

F2::
    Toggle := !Toggle
    if Toggle {
        settimer, fire_stop, on
        sleep 120                   ; offset between timers
        settimer, fire, on
        gosub fire
    } else {
        settimer, fire, off
        settimer, fire_stop, off
        gosub fire_stop
    }
return

fire:
    tooltip  "key is down"  
    send {LCtrl down}
return

fire_stop:
    tooltip  "key is up" 
    send {LCtrl up}
return
```